# Find and element on Android using Selenium and Appium

Tags: android, selenium, c#-4.0, appium

I'm using this code in order to find an element on my Android (Native App) device using selenium and Appium :

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
var phone = wait.Until(x => x.FindElements(By.Id("foo")));
```

The problem is that Selenium finds the element only seemingly. Meaning it finds it, but with no attributes at all.

But when using :

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

everything works like a charm.

I have tried to increase the seconds in the driver's wait, but it didn't help.

Comment: seems like a Duplicate

Comment: Previous one was deleted due to wrong description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the element is not getting loaded at the time script is performing an operation on it.
Try to add a visibility check before performing any operation on that element

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.locator);
```

Comment: in addition , for  IList , we can use this:
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Locator)